# Firefox linux (centos) responsive design image scaling

Tags: html, css, linux, firefox, responsive-design

I have an arrow in circle. [image] CSS:

```
img{
        float:left;
        width: 15%;
        max-width: 33px;
        height: auto;
    }
```

In windows xp (ie8,safari,opera,ff,chrome) I checked everything is ok. The image is getting bigger and smaller - no any lines. But in linux  some lines appear from the right and at the bottom of the picture. I checked image several times - there are no any lines. How can it be fixed?

Linux:centos 6.4 64
FF:25,26

Comment: @Mr Lister I tried FF 25 and 26. In 27 not - because there is no rpm for 27 yet for centos, but I think it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help you. I solved this problem by setting different name for all images. It seems that it helped. Anyway I opened a bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975358